# Summarizing and plotting several combined relationships with LMER

Tags: r, mixed-model, multiple-regression, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I want to see if there is a significant relationship between *predictor* and *value*.

I've measured these two variables in 6 different conditions (not a full 3 x 3 design because *feature1* and *feature2* can't be equal).

```
subject   feature1  feature2   predictor  value
    1     shape     color      -0.06     -0.24
    2     shape     color      -0.32     -0.57
    3     shape     color      -0.45     -0.68
    4     shape     color      -0.89     -1.65
    5     shape     color       0.14     -0.10
    6     shape     color      -0.56      0.26
    7     shape     color      -0.54      0.49
    8     shape     color      -0.20      0.55
    9     shape     color       0.10      0.42
    10    shape     color       0.30     -0.26
    1     texture   color      -0.04     -1.04
    2     texture   color       0.02      0.77
    3     texture   color      -0.58     -0.63
    4     texture   color      -0.31     -0.06
    5     texture   color       0.43     -0.39
    6     texture   color      -0.27     -0.48
    7     texture   color      -0.87     -0.16
    8     texture   color      -0.20      0.57
    9     texture   color       0.34      0.80
    10    texture   color       0.51      0.20
    1     color     shape      -0.36     -0.23
    2     color     shape       0.15     -1.19
    ....
```

I can model this effect, averaged across conditions

```
lm.output <- lm(value.mean ~ predictor.mean, data=d)
```

but I don't assume that the subjects will behave similarly in each condition, so averaging by subjects like this isn't the best approach.

Within each condition (e.g. for "shape" and "color"), the relationship between *predictor* and *value* is more or less strong, but it goes in the same direction across all conditions (kind of akin to saying "there's a small, but positive relationship in all cases", similar to a meta-analysis). This is the pattern of results I hope to convey.

How should I best model this? My guess is like this:

```
lmer.output <- lmer(value ~ predictor + feature1:feature2 + (1|subject), data=dataset)
```

and then take the t-statistic and estimate for *predictor* to report. Is this valid? If so, is there a good way to plot this to show the relationship between *predictor* and *value*?

Here's the dataset:

```
dataset           <- expand.grid(subject = factor(seq_len(10)), 
                                 feature1 = factor(c("color", "shape", "texture"), 
                                            levels = c("color", "shape", "texture")), 
                                 feature2 = factor(c("color", "shape", "texture"), 
                                            levels = c("color", "shape", "texture")))
dataset           <-  dataset[dataset$feature1 != dataset$feature2,]
dataset$predictor <- rnorm(nrow(dataset), sd = 0.20) + 
                     with(dataset, rnorm(length(levels(subject)), sd = 0.256)[subject])
dataset$value     <- dataset$predictor + rnorm(nrow(dataset), sd = 0.60)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# for reproducible random data
set.seed(120)
```

One thing you could do is add random slopes for each permutation of the features.

```
dataset$features <- with(dataset, paste(feature1, feature2, sep=":"))
mod <- lmer(value ~ predictor + (predictor|features) + (1|subject), data = dataset)

fixef(mod)
## (Intercept)   predictor 
## -0.02124363  1.42935194

coef(mod)

## $subject
##    (Intercept) predictor
## 1  -0.08973177  1.429352
## 2  -0.03445224  1.429352
## 3   0.01329694  1.429352
## 4  -0.46300970  1.429352
## 5   0.02204660  1.429352
## 6   0.15729723  1.429352
## 7  -0.12593073  1.429352
## 8   0.27824801  1.429352
## 9   0.25601688  1.429352
## 10 -0.22621754  1.429352

## $features
##               (Intercept) predictor
## color:shape    0.06764126  1.521571
## color:texture -0.04575920  1.403917
## shape:color   -0.18606342  1.258349
## shape:texture  0.06951424  1.523515
## texture:color -0.01961882  1.431038
## texture:shape -0.01317585  1.437722
```

You could pull these formulas from the `lmer` object and plot a line for each feature permutation (and the overall effect if you want).

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

formulas_from_lmer <- coef(mod)$features %>% select(intercept = 1, slope = 2)
formulas_from_lmer$features <- row.names(formulas_from_lmer)
row.names(formulas_from_lmer) <- NULL

ggplot(dataset, aes(x = predictor, y = value, color = features)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = features)) +
  geom_abline(data = formulas_from_lmer,
    mapping = aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, color = features)) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = fixef(mod)[[1]], slope = fixef(mod)[[2]]),
    color = 'gray', size = 1.5, alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

As you can see from the graph above, the `lmer` model assumes the slope for each feature permutation will be closer to the overall slope. If you calculate the formulas by hand, you can see how the slopes may differ more substantially:

```
fit_lm_and_extract_params <- function(y, x, param_num) {
  coef(lm(y ~ x))[[param_num]]
}

formulas_by_hand <- dataset %>% group_by(features) %>%
  summarize(
    intercept = fit_lm_and_extract_params(value, predictor, 1),
    slope = fit_lm_and_extract_params(value, predictor, 2)
  )

ggplot(dataset, aes(x = predictor, y = value, color = features)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = features)) +
  geom_abline(data = formulas_by_hand,
    mapping = aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, color = features)) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = fixef(mod)[[1]], slope = fixef(mod)[[2]]),
              color = 'gray', size = 1.5)
```

[image]

Of course, these formulas fit by hand are not taking into account the `(1|subject)` in the original model. You could either refit the `lmer` model without random intercepts for subjects or adjust each value based on the by-subject intercept and recalculate the formulas by hand.

Comment: +1, Welcome to CV. This is a really nice contribution; I hope we'll see more.

Comment: What's the rationale for having features as a random intercept (not slope, right?) rather than including it as fixed factor in the model?

Comment: Ah! So random intercepts and random slopes are both estimated for `features`. The intercept is implicit in the random effects structure, so `(predictor|features)` == `(1+predictor|features)`. Compare `coef(mod)$subject` to `coef(mod)$features`: the intercept for each subject varies, but the slope doesn't. For features, both intercepts and slopes vary. To your more general point about fixed effects: it would make sense to me to include `features` as fixed if you cared about comparing the effect in one feature1:feature2 permutation to another, or wanted to compare each permutation to baseline.